# HTTP error 500 when requesting google big query API using service account

Tags: google-bigquery

I have been using Big query to generate reports through a web service for a year now, however in the past month or so I have noticed HTTP 500 errors in response to most of my query requests even though no changes have been made to the web service. In my current setup I make 5 simultaneous queries and often 4 out of the 5 queries fail with 500 error. At times all 5 queries are returned but in recent times this rarely happens rendering my application almost unusable.

I use server to server authentication using my service account token and my big query client app is closely modeled on the example given here -

https://developers.google.com/bigquery/articles/dashboard#class

Here is the full error message -

> HttpError: https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/1021946877460/queries?alt=json returned "Unexpected. Please try again.">

Snippet of my bigquery client -

```
def generateToken():
    """
    generates OAuth2.0 token/credentials for login to google big query
    """
    credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
        KEY, 
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery")
    return credentials

class BigQueryClient(object):
    def authenticate(self, credentials):
        http = httplib2.Http(proxy_info = httplib2.ProxyInfo(
                                 socks.PROXY_TYPE_HTTP, 
                                 PROXY_IP, 
                                 PROXY_PORT))
        http = credentials.authorize(http)
        return http

    def __init__(self, credentials, project):
        http = self.authenticate(credentials)
        self.service = build('bigquery', 'v2', http=http)
```

Please let me know if I am doing something incorrectly here or if anything has changed on the bigquery backend such as limits to the number of query requests allowed over a certain period of time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

500s are always BigQuery bugs. I believe I've tracked down one of your errors in the BigQuery server logs, and am investigating.

Comment: Any updates on the fix to this issue ? Just want to get an idea of the timeline on when a fix might be released. Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: Yes... I've got a fix, it will likely go out in next week's release, usually tuesday or wednesday.

Comment: Just wanted to check if the fix was released. I am still seeing the same error message.

Comment: Since we had a major release (streaming, table decorators) this week, we didn't do our normal release process. The fix for this is in, but it will be a couple of days before it is in production. I'll update this thread when it is.