# Steaming insert / insertAll - long delay?

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-api-python-client

I'm streaming data into a table on BigQuery from the google api for python.

I get a 200 OK with no 'insertErrors' key in the response from bigQuery:

```
{u'kind': u'bigquery#tableDataInsertAllResponse'}
```

If I query my table there are only 2 rows, despite me having inserted several additional records a little while ago (20 minutes+).

I can't see any errors anywhere - can someone advise me on how to debug this issue?

Comment: Please share some job id you've just executed, usually there is a slight delay, couple of minutes, but shouldn't be in ten minutes range.

Comment: I'm very new to bigquery, so excuse me if this is a stupid question, but how do I get/find the job id for a streaming insert?

Comment: well similar PHP code exists here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22150608/how-to-troubleshoot-get-error-response-when-you-run-invalid-bigquery-jobs

Comment: Streaming inserts work differently I think. I am following the method outlined at the bottom of this page: https://developers.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery (see the Python tab of the example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19145783/1607103

I resolved the issue I was experiencing by creating a new dataset and new tables within it. Everything is now working perfectly and data is visible seconds after adding it.  I am at a stage in my project where table structures are changing frequently, which seems to be the cause of the issue. I will ensure that modified tables have different names for now.

I am extremely concerned that bigquery is experiencing issues with no visibility. It doesn't fill me with confidence that there are no errors and there is no indication (that I am aware of) that something is going wrong.